# How to build a new list of objects, each with a new property, given an initial list of objects in ES6 without loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

If I have a list of objects, eg:

```
const poeple = [
    {name: "Johhny", born:1980, passed:2080},
    {name: "Jenny", born:1990, passed:2093},
    ...{name: "Jan", born:1999, passed:2096}
    ];
```

I found out how to make a new list, with the ages like this:

```
const ages = people.map(person => person.passed - person.born);
```

And I can add the property 'age' to the original people, like this:

```
people.map(person => person["age"] = person.passed - person.born);
```

But, is there a (quick/efficient/eloquent) way to just make a new array, with each object having the additional property, as I don't want to change the original array?

I tried to use the array push method, but that just adds objects one at a time, with a loop, is there any other way to do this with less code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` method with spread syntax in object.

```js
const people = [{name: "Johhny", born:1980, passed:2080},{name: "Jenny", born:1990, passed:2093},{name: "Jan", born:1999, passed:2096}];
 
const result = people.map(person => ({
  ...person,
  age: person.passed - person.born
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and create the new object by appending the `age` to the existing object using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const people = [{name: "Johhny", born:1980, passed:2080},{name: "Jenny", born:1990, passed:2093},{name: "Jan", born:1999, passed:2096}];

const result = people.map(o => Object.assign({
  age: o.passed - o.born
}, o));

console.log(result);
```